# Search url automatically in mod_rewrite version

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to set a forms action property automatically with mod_rewrite after clicking on a search button?

normal url is this:
http://www.website.com/search.php?search=name

mod_rewrite url is this:
http://www.website.com/search/name.html

I know that it is possible to set a mod_rewrite version of the page with htaccess, but how would I have the form go directly to the mod_rewrite url?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /search\.php\?search=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /search/%2.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/(.*).html$ /search.php?name=$1 [L]
```

It should automatically turn the normal link into the mod_rewrite link.

Comment: Just a note, 301 is the default for R, 302 is the one that needs to be specified. Doesn't really matter, just worth noting