# Link conversion in mod rewrite .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to change my long url to something short I did it successfully but after sending get info URL is not chanining to what I want like I search for something and it show my url like this

```
/search.php?q=a&limit=150&siz=any
```

so I want to convert it automatically in url bar like this

```
/car/150/any
```

**I am using this**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?q=$1&limit=$2&siz=$3 [R,NC]
```

but it is not converting link automaticly however it works when I write in url like

```
/car/150/any
```

same related question is asked by someone here so I need something like that for my link

[Search url automatically in mod_rewrite version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681669/search-url-automatically-in-mod-rewrite-version)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^search/([^_]+)/([0-9]+)/([^_]+).html$ search.php?act=$1&limit=$2&siz=$3 [L]
```

access url with

```
search/car/150/any
```

better put constant ^search as page identifier to avoiding conflict with other url rewrite,

```
([^_]+) can receive string input
([0-9]+) only can receive number input
```