# .htaccess modrewrite URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on mod rewrite code and currently stuck on 1 problem I don't know why problem is happning.
When user search for something url looks like this

```
/search.php?q=car&limit=150&siz=any
```

I have converted it to like this. .htaccess automatically convert the link to like this

```
/car/150/any
```

But the problem when user search again url changes to something like this

```
/car/150/any?q=books&limit=150&siz=any
```

Which I don't want so please tell me what do I do

Here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /search\.php\?q=(.*)\&limit=(.*)\&siz=(.*?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?q=$1&limit=$2&siz=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned here before [Link conversion in mod rewrite .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863000/link-conversion-in-mod-rewrite-htaccess)

1.I suggest you add ^search as identifier to avoid conflict

2.query search should be end of other parameter, inputing string at first might occured link unreadable

Here my new answerd Edited based on your new question

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^search/([^_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ search.php?limit=$1&siz=$2&q=$3 [L]
```

if you want to call script within you web page, call using link [http://yoursite.com/150/any/Your Search String](http://yoursite.com/150/any/Your%20Search%20String)

dont call by `search.php?q=book&limit=150&siz=any` just past your variable int Your Search String above

Comment: Thanks for answering however I just solved the problem I just changed the action in the form to something like this
"http://example.com/search.php" from "" and it solved the problem also I am using the same code I just mentioned above.

Comment: yes that I was mean, call script with your url rewrite link